# How can I write a type trait to check if a type is convertible to another by a non-narrowing conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, sfinae, type-traits

C++11 introduced uniform initialization, which comes with the desirable feature of forbidding implicit narrowing conversions.  For example, `int i{2.2}` should be an error.

Unfortunately, for backwards-compatibility reasons with C++03, GCC since 4.7 gives only a warning for these.

GCC's [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-Wnarrowing-192) suggests that this extension doesn't apply in SFINAE contexts, but it appears to be wrong:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename From, typename To>
class is_list_convertible_helper
{
  template <typename To2>
  static void requires_conversion(To2 t);

  template <typename From2, typename To2,
      typename = decltype(requires_conversion<To2>({std::declval<From2>()}))>
  //                                               ^ Braced initializer
  static std::true_type helper(int);

  template <typename From2, typename To2>
  static std::false_type helper(...);

public:
  using type = decltype(helper<From, To>(0));
};

template <typename From, typename To>
class is_list_convertible
  : public is_list_convertible_helper<From, To>::type
{ };

static_assert(!is_list_convertible<double, int>::value,
    "double -> int is narrowing!");
```

GCC 4.9.1 gives this output

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class From2, class To2, class> static std::true_type is_list_convertible_helper<From, To>::helper(int) [with From2 = double; To2 = int; <template-parameter-1-3> = <missing>]’:
foo.cpp:18:31:   required from ‘class is_list_convertible_helper<double, int>’
foo.cpp:22:7:   required from ‘class is_list_convertible<double, int>’
foo.cpp:26:48:   required from here
foo.cpp:10:46: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘std::declval<double>()’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
       typename = decltype(requires_conversion<To2>({std::declval<From2>()}))>
                                              ^
foo.cpp:26:1: error: static assertion failed: double -> int is narrowing!
 static_assert(!is_list_convertible<double, int>::value,
 ^
```

Short of adding specializations for every narrowing conversion, is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Check numeric limits manually?

Comment: @Yakk What check would I use, exactly?  Which conversions are and are not narrowing has nothing to do with the actual range or precision of the types involved.

Comment: @Tavain Barring the constants rule, when isn't it to do with precision/types?  Detect float->integer, float->less precice float, integer->float, integer->integer that is not a superset.  All look like type traits and precision things?

Comment: @Yakk I just meant it doesn't have to do with the particular range or precision of the types involved.  long->int is a narrowing conversion even if they have they same range.  Also GCC thinks `is_list_convertible<double, std::string>` due to the `std::string(std::initializer_list<char>)` constructor.  Not sure how to solve that with `numeric_limits`.

Comment: 8.5.4/7 says `long->int` is not narrowing if they have the same range.  Now, the `long double->double->float` chain does not technically depend on precision/range, but everything else does.

Comment: @Yakk You're right, sorry!  I expected it to be based on the integer conversion rank for integral types, but it's based on the range of representable values instead.  I find that odd honestly.

Comment: I think you've simply found a compiler bug, and you should report it on the GCC bugzilla if it hasn't been reported already. Until it's fixed, you might consider using another compiler. Testing shows that clang does get this right.

Comment: Try -Werror. In fact always use -Werror.

Comment: @n.m. So that you'd get an error for a program that is supposed to have no errors and no warnings? No, that won't work. :)

Comment: @hvd Already [reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63723).  But I'd like to still target GCC 4.9 so a workaround would be great.

Comment: @n.m Sadly that doesn't work, `-Werror` or `Werror=narrowing` just turns the warning into an error instead of SFINAE-ing it away.

Comment: Bummer :( Back to drawing board then.

Comment: And I thought I had a workaround that I could post as an answer, but I had an important typo in it, and fixing the typo showed that it completely failed. Sorry, I fear you may be out of luck.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that "narrowing conversions are still considered ill-formed in SFINAE context." Or was this edited since?

Comment: The documentation states that but is wrong; it gives only a warning.  That's what this post/bug report is about.

Comment: @TavianBarnes -- ISO only specifies that a compiler must produce a "diagnostic" when it sees ill-formed code; it's up to that compiler what *kind* (warning, error, fatal, or even informational) of diagnostic message to output.  This means that GCC is well within its rights to emit a warning here -- or are you trying to say that GCC should not emit a -Wnarrowing diagnostic from within SFINAE context?

Comment: In a deduced context, a narrowing conversion within a braced initializer should cause a substitution failure, rather than simply a diagnostic.  Anyway, the [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63723) has been fixed now.

Comment: Good -- make that into an answer, and you'll get an upvote from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, this is a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63723) in GCC.  The bug has existed since `-std=c++11` has been supported (though it worked in GCC 4.6 with `-std=c++0x`).  It has been fixed for the upcoming GCC 5 release, but probably won't be backported to GCC 4.9.